# header within html document not working - new server

Tags: php, http-headers

I moved my documents to a new host and the headers stopped working(refresh,redirect,etc).They used to work in my old server.I have googled and tried adding a ob_start before sending headers, that did not work.

Here is a part of the code...

```
if(isset($_GET['reflink']))
                        {
                            echo '<h3>Already Logged In<h3><p>Please logout before registering an account.Redirecting you back to where you came from...';
                            header('Refresh: 3; url="http://www.xacnr.com'.$_GET['reflink'].'"');
                        }
```

*It used to work before, it must be a problem with the server settings or something :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A short answer is:

**It is not possible to send http headers after the output of anything else.**

So if you want to output headers, you must do this **at the beginning** of your output. To be even more precise: HTTP-Headers must be the first thing of your output, if you have to send them - before anything else.

Please read the documentation:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php
http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

Please be also aware of the fact that **the Refresh-Header is AFAIK not part of the official HTTP-Standard**. It's a jurassic artifact from Netscape which will be still accepted and interpreted by most browsers, but this may change even without special notice.

If you need such a refresh and if you want to stay on the safe side, you should consider using the Meta-Refresh within the HTML-Header.

Please read here:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh

BTW: It's also a bad idea to use unsanitized, unprocessed values from $_GET, $_POST etc. Your example should never be used in any public available environment.

Comment: It worked before lol with output before header :| (was using serversfree before)

Comment: I cannot believe that the shown example worked before. At least it should not. If it really worked, something really weird happens on your server. Maybe output buffering was activated. But it's definetly a wrong implementation and you should change it. Please refere to: http://www.php.net/manual/en/outcontrol.configuration.php for further information.

Comment: the headers are protected in the php version I have.Why do I need to sanitize them?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean with protected headers but IMHO the superglobals with user input like $_GET, $_POST shouldn't be used without sanitizing. You might be interested in this (older) article: http://www.phparch.com/2010/07/never-use-_get-again/

Comment: BTW: Even _if_ it worked before because of a strange server environment or enabled output buffering: The implementation is wrong. HTTP Headers must be the first output if they exist. They cannot be send after anything else. If it worked it only means that PHP modified the wrong output and either may have discarded headers or moved it to the beginning which both is bad practice and simply wrong ;)

Comment: I heard that there is some protection mechanism against Header Injections :| I have set my DNS to serversfree ip, the header works http://xacnr.com/default/secure/login.php?action=login - Redirect Works!

Comment: Thanks, I modify the code and preprocess GET with header at the top .Then in the html block I will echo the html code.

Comment: The problem is not the header - it's the unsanitized $_GET. So it is only a recommendation - but in general i would avoid any usage of unsanitized input. But it's your site. BTW: You should turn off directory listing on your webserver or at least put some empty index.html files in the subfolders - it's not a big deal, but it should also be fixed.

Answer (score 2):

**You do an output (`echo`) before you send the header:**

```
echo '<h3>Already Logged In<h3><p>Please logout before registering an account.Redirecting you back to where you came from...';
header('Refresh: 3; url="http://www.xacnr.com'.$_GET['reflink'].'"');
```

### **The simple but strict rule is:**

## **No output before the header!**

---

From the Docs:

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is
>   sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP.
>   It is a very common error to read code with include, or require,
>   functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty
>   lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem
>   exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

Comment: it did work on my old server :| I did not change the code.I downloaded and uploaded the same files.Was it changed in a new php version?

Comment: Your old server probably had output buffering on.

Comment: maybe...but I added a ob_start at the top of my php script...but it still did not work